# Dynamic Filter for CPI

Tags: odata, sap-cpi

Need to make the country dynamic in the query.

Current Query:
`$top=4&$select=CustomerID,CompanyName,Country&$filter=Country eq 'Italy'`

The country 'Italy' should be dynamically picked up from the header.

- Country field in header:
  [image: Country field in header]
- The output XML is showing the country value:
  [image: The output XML is showing the country value]

Tried changing the query to:
`$top=4&$select=CustomerID,CompanyName,Country&$filter=Country eq ${in.header.country}`. This gives a error and doesn't work.

Tried changing the query to:
`$top=4&$select=CustomerID,CompanyName,Country&$filter=Country eq ${in.header.country}`. This gives a error and doesn't work.

Expect the data to be filtered based on country.